# Sencha Touch dynamic store URL on click

Tags: url, dynamic, sencha-touch, store, carousel

I would like my store in Sencha touch to load a different PHP file depending on which item in my carousel is clicked. Each item in my carousel has itemid: {number} assigned. This is my store at the moment:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'One',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/carousel2store/Carousel 2_files/get-album.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'albums'
            }
        },....etc
```

I've tried altering the store like this which gives '/carousel2store/Carousel 2_files/get-album2.php', but I would like to make the number 2 dynamic, so it changes on click:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'One',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/carousel2store/Carousel 2_files/get-album' + '2' +'.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'albums'
            }
        },
```

I've tried to add the itemid

```
url: '/carousel2store/Carousel 2_files/get-album' + '{itemid}' +'.php', and
url: '/carousel2store/Carousel 2_files/get-album' + '{data.itemid}' +'.php',
```

But I've had no luck so far. A very helpful guy on the sencha forum suggested I try this:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'One',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/carousel2store/Carousel 2_files/get-album{itemId}.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'albums'
            }
        }
    });

    store.proxy.url = store.proxy.url.replace('{itemId}', 1);

    console.log(store);
```

...but I can't get it to work in my testing when clicking with the mouse, I think because it loads the store already before the carousel and item tap listener (at least it didn't work for me in my testing with the mouse). I think I need a way of force updating the store name straight after item click.

Thanks in advance

:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a somewhat similar problem where I need to dynamically change the URL on my proxy. I found that this works particularly well in most cases, just be sure to handle your load sequence properly.

```
store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('YourStore');
store.setProxy({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://www.yoururl.com?foo=bar',
});
```

Comment: I'd like to add that according to the API getProxy returns the proxy values, where setProxy allows you to change values. See the API Docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-setProxy

Answer (score 3):

Great workaround M69!

Integrated into the store definition through the **beforeload** listener:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Accounts', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    config: {
        autoLoad: false,

        model: 'MyApp.model.Account',

        scope: this,

        listeners: {
            beforeload: function(store){
                store.setProxy({
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: MyApp.getUrl('accounts', {token:MyApp.getToken()}),
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        rootProperty: 'response.accounts'
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, among all solutions I like yours the best. Could you please explain the parameters of this method: getUrl(parameter1,parameter2)? I don't understand what is the 1st and 2nd params and their types.

Comment: Hi Franva, that method was just an internal helper to return the URL based on the page requested and provided headers. You just need to pass the URL there.

Answer (score 2):

I have a same question with yours, i solved it by the following way:

```
store.getProxy().url = './getnotes?folderName=' + folderName;
store.load();
```

I didn't set url in proxy of the store when defined it, and set the autoLoad to false.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work.....

```
var str = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStoreId');
str.setProxy({
type: 'ajax',
url: 'URL1',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this successfully. i.e. pass the url into the load operation:

```
var aStore = this.getMyStore(),
    url = 'data/assertions.php';

aStore.load({
    url: url,
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
        console.log(records);
    },
    scope: this
})
```